# Can't download file with UTF-8 characters in its name in Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, utf-8, cloud

I'm in dire need for help.
In my android application, I'm having problem with downloading files from server contaning UTF-8 charaters in its name. With regular characters it works (english alphabet). Server receives UTF-8 characters as "?".

Example:

File named as "Preview-icon.png" works, but file named "Preview-iconČ.png" dosen't work, and I get "File not found error", as it searches for "Preview-icon?.png" and not "Preview-iconČ".

I have been searching solution for a week, and I still haven't found it.

Below is my code for downloading files:

```
public void downloadFile(String url, String dest_file_path) {
    try {

        File dest_file = new File(dest_file_path);
        URL u = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
        int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();
        DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());
        byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
        stream.readFully(buffer);
        stream.close();
        DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dest_file));
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

        Log.e("file","not found!");
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("IO","error");
        return;
    }
```

Parameter url is a regular string containing url, Eg. "http://127.0.0.1:10001/downloadfile?filepath=/home/nikola/Desktop/Preview-icon.png&filename=Preview-icon.png". And dest_file_path is destenation of location in internal storage, Eg.  "/mnt/sdcard/Preview-icon.png".

Comment: which browser are you using ?

Comment: @Mrunal None, it's plain code written in java.

Comment: How are you encoding non-ASCII characters in the URL? *Hint: It's required that you do.* `Preview-iconČ.png` should be encoded as `Preview-icon%C4%8C.png`, I believe.

Comment: @Andreas I have used URLEncoder, but It seems that I deleted it while try-and-error. Even with URLEncoder, it dosen't work with UTF-8 charaters.

Comment: Maybe the server doesn't support UTF-8 in the URL, if it;s an old server.

Comment: @Andreas Well,it's not an old server, I've been using Tonido platform, and It's fairly new. Other people with this server seems to be using Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 and it works. The problem is that I don't know how to implement it in download and upload in my android app :/

Answer (score 0):

What's the Charset used by the sever application, it seems the charsets used by client and sever are not matched, please have a try that both sides use `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for help, I have found solution. I have to encode only part of the string that has UTF-8 characters.

So I only encode "Preview-iconč.png" part of the string with URLEncode, add it to final string, and bam, it works like a charm. :D

Comment: So I was right? `Preview-iconČ.png` had to be encoded as `Preview-icon%C4%8C.png`?

Comment: @Andreas Well, yes. I was already encoding the whole URL string, so I figured that wasn't the problem, but It was, i only needed to encode path of file, and file name. Thank you :)

Comment: Good. Now, either accept your own answer, so people can see the solution, or delete the question, if you think it won't be helpful to others. in this case, the issue was in code that's not even visible, so I'd go with the latter.